# Relationship between REST API and Google Cloud Endpoints?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

Is it that Cloud Endpoints *enable* the implementation of a REST API?

It looks like it is possible to create a REST API by just using Flask to handle different methods (GET, POST, PUT, etc.), so where exactly does Cloud Endpoints meet REST API?

Or, perhaps it is that Cloud Endpoints lets you create your own API service that can be consumed by many apps by providing them their own client ID + client secret?

I am trying to demystify what exactly is scope of usage of Cloud Endpoints.

Comment: Cloud Endpoints is just a middle man between the client (consumer) of your API services. REST is just a convention using HTTP verbs for communicating (data transfer and commands). Cloud Endpoints also supports gRPC instead of REST.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud endpoint is an [esp](https://github.com/cloudendpoints/esp) which means that is a proxy between your APIs (rest or grpc) and the rest of the world.

This endpoint allows you to expose a clean interface and the underlayer implementation can be the mess. You can define endpoints and route query to different implementation: functions, VM, cloud run, app engine,.... And even on other cloud!

You can manage authentications (especially API keys), rate limit, logging, tracing,...

And you can transform a query to another one (change param name, add Decatur default values,...)

It's very powerful and based on open API (swagger). 
For example, it allows you to expose a service and to migrate it piece by piece transparently.

The best level is apigee but it's expensive!!